# How to get Translation working on CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, translation

After reading and watching tutorials online, I can't get translations to work on CakePHP.

My website is in English by default but I want the option to switch it in French.

There's an empty "i18n" table in the database. There are also a Locale/default.pot and Locale/cake.pot files. I used PoEdit to generate a Locale/fra/default.po file (+ default.mo).

I read that I must type

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra')
```

in Config/bootstrap.php and it didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: `Config.language` ...? Shouldn't that be string?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen my bad. it was a typo. but it still not working.

Comment: What happens if you change `fra` to `fr`?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen nothing new happened :(